# Date Picker returns date in m-d-y but need d-m-y

Tags: date, datepicker

I can't figure out how to get the date to be saved in the database, in the format dd-mm-yy rather than mm-dd-yy

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#pickup_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
  } );
  </script>
```

and my form field is as follow:

```
    <?= FORM::label('pickup_date', __('Pick Up Date'), array('for'=>'pickup_date'))?>
    <?= FORM::input('pickup_date', Request::current()->post('pickup_date'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'pickup_date', 'placeholder'=>__('Select Date')))?>
```

*Can anyone please shed some light on this matter, as I really don't see what I'm going wrong...*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I have always used it as mentioned in the docs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Usage:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( 2007, 1 - 1, 26 ) );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Khal I'll give that a go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Khal for your input, unfortunately that didn't do the trick for me... so after further research I found a solution that worked for me:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#from-datepicker").datepicker({ 
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    $("#from-datepicker").on("change", function () {
        var fromdate = $(this).val();
        alert(fromdate);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Hope this will help others who bumped into the same issue.